# Construction of Gdiplus::Font in own Constructor

Tags: c++, fonts, gdi+

I am trying to construct a Gdiplus::Font inside my own Class constructor.

My Class looks like this:

drawGui.h:

```
class drawGui {
private:
     Gdiplus::Font* font; // Better would be std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::Font>

public:
    drawGui();
    ~drawGui();

    void draw(Gdiplus::Bitmap* image);
};
```

I tryed the following construction methods in  my drawGui.cpp:

```
drawGui::drawGui() { 
    Gdiplus::Font fontBuffer(L"Arial", 12);
    font = fontBuffer.Clone(); // Exception
}

drawGui::drawGui() { // Compiles but font == NULL
    font = new Gdiplus::Font(L"Arial", 12);
}

drawGui::~drawGui() {
    delete font;
}

void drawGui::draw(Gdiplus::Bitmap* image) { /* Draw the Font onto an Image */ }
```

My draw() function is geting called once a second so I want to store the font object in my class and reuse it everytime I call draw().

I am using the latest version of VS2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that GdiplusStartup() was called by another class. Gdi+ was  active in my class methods, but not in the class constructor.